# The continuity assumption on the limiting c.f. in Levy's continuity theorem.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions, levy-processes

I am looking for an example that shows we can't drop the continuity assumption on the limiting characteristic function in Levy's continuity theorem.

I got some hints from my professor that use a sequence of normal distributions {$ \mu_n$ } with $ \mu_n$ having mean 0 and variance n.

Could anyone help me out with how this construction works?

Comment: So what is the limit of the characteristic functions of the $\mu_n$ in the professor's  hint. Is it continuous?  Is it the sequence $\mu_n$ tight?

Comment: Why can't you follow the precise suggestion by your teacher? (Unrelated: Are you still using two accounts on mse?)